# Using jQuery to Get Rid of Text in a html label element

Tags: jquery, html

How can you use jQuery to get rid of text between the `<label>` tags?

I would need to keep the `<input>` within the `<label>` but get rid of the "Clinical Vendor" text.

```
<label for="form">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ar" name="b" value="Clinical Vendor" id="form">Clinical Vendor
</label>
```

I have tried `jQuery('label').text('');` but that seems to get rid of the `input` tag as well.

EDIT: Everyone came up with pretty much the same solution using nodes. TIL! Thanks, everybody!

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to wrap the text in another element, such as a `span`, then call `text('')` on that. If you want to keep your HTML as-is, you'll need to go filtering through the text nodes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery remove label text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878456/jquery-remove-label-text)

Comment: @putvande I am hacking together an interface using a Wordpress plugin. I don't have control of the HTML....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `input` tag can't have any child nodes since it is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element).
You need to target the text associated with the `label` and remove it.

[About nodeType (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

```
$('label')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  }).remove();
```

[Code from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might work for you:

```
$("label").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; }).remove();
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/jrfdtL1w/1/%20DEMO)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('label').contents().last()[0].textContent='';
```

Comment: Ah right didn't see the text after the input. Nvm then.

Comment: Adjusted the answer accordingly. Thx for pointing out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the text node with a blank one:

```
            function isTextNode() {
              return (this.nodeType === 3);
            }
            $("label").contents().filter(isTextNode).replaceWith(
              document.createTextNode("")
            );
```